# d3 line rendering off page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to make a simple line graph with d and an angular directive. The svg area is showing up on the page, but the line portion is rendering off the page.

I am using d3 v4

I did scale the x and y data. My console.log shows the x and y values should all fit into the svg's width and height. I have been researching for a while and cant seem to find any solution that works.

Here is the angular code:

```
    graphics.directive('lineVis', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        val: '=',
        grouped: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var margin = 25,
            width = 960,
            height = 500;
            data = [{_id:16998.0, total: 1854},{_id:16999.0, total: 2157},{_id:17000.0, total: 2389},{_id:17001.0, total: 2187},{_id:17002.0, total: 1973},{_id:17003.0, total: 1050}];

        console.log(data.length);
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([margin, width-margin])
            .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d._id;}));
            //[d3.min(data, function(d){return d._id}), d3.max(data, function(d){return d._id})])

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([margin, height-margin])
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
                return d.total;
            })]);

        var line = d3.line()
            .x(function(d){
                console.log('Y: '+ y(d.total) + ' X: ' + x(d._id));
                return (d._id);
            })
            .y(function(d){
                return y(d.total);
            })


        var svg = d3.select(element[0])
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width+margin)
            .attr('height', height+margin);

        svg.selectAll('*').remove() //remove all previous elements

        svg.append('path')
            .attr('class', 'line')
            .attr('stroke', '#777')
            .attr('d', line(data));
        }   
    }
});
```

And the css:

```
    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
```

I know the html is working because the svg and line are rendering, the line is just rendering of screen.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append a `g` element to the svg, translated to the margin values. Look at Mike's example https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3019563.

To prevent code duplication, subtract the margins from the width/height and define the result as the width/height. Now you don't have to keep saying "- margin" everywhere.

```
//in case you want different values per side
var margin = {top: 25, right: 25, bottom: 25, left: 25};

var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select(element[0])
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width+margin)
            .attr('height', height+margin);
            .append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Eric! I agree this makes to code easier to read and more flexible. (as well as actually add the margins)

I also left out the x scale on the d3.line()
should be:

```
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d){
            console.log('Y: '+ y(d.total) + ' X: ' + x(d._id));
            return x(d._id); // <-- added x call
        })
        .y(function(d){
            return y(d.total);
        })
```

The line renders now! however it is now inverted... baby steps

EDIT:

when I say inverted, I mean the line graph starts in the upper right hand corner

SOLUTION:

switch .domain for the y scaler:

```
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([0, height])
            .domain([d3.max(data, function(d){
                return d.total;
            }), 0]);
```

Hope this help someone else!